# Directory Mismatch while including other PHP files in it

Tags: php

I am working on a project (the first one) and got this error :

[I am NOOB and new]
First of all **my directory** is something like this:  (Adding on main files)
[Yellow lines point to files and the purple one leads to a folder.]
[image]

I am working on the User Section right now.

I made a header folder and added a header.php file to it. which contains a header(): void. this header function basically has my navbar (few things are retrieved with DB). Also this same file is linked with .css and .js from AdminSection.

Now while making this function I was doing try and error on my user dashboard so it is now working 100% correctly as I wanted.

But when I included this function into another PHP file for let's say UserProfile it doesn't work anymore as all the included files in Header.php were working for UserDashboard.php (since it is in another directory which is working because of my try and error.)

I searched for a bit about this and found no solution but to make a header file for every directory which seems to be stupid.

Any solutions for it?

**A Snippet from my header file if required**
[The paths are working for Dashboard.php but not for files in another directory. I want a solution where I have only one header.php and it works for every file no matter its directory]
[image]

Comment: your `header(location` should be absolute from doc root (since it is essentially a URL) - in fact it could include the URL, but that's not necessary. everything after:`www.mywebsite.com` - itshould start with a `/`

Comment: You could have posted the piece of code as text, and not as an image, see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: your `include` is relative which might cause problems when you move files. One way to make it absolute is this `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\Website\UserSection..."`

Comment: '/' and '\' are different? When I try to include any folder in include () PHPStrom suggests '\' and trust me I just noticed this. Also, what will be my root folder? Bumblepix or Website

Comment: you should use `/`, also the code after header() is executed if you dont use exit

Comment: @Kinglish this not working :) I tried `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\Website\AdminSection\CSS\main.css";?>" />` and its not working.

Comment: no, the document_root is not for href links, just system paths. Use forward slashes for href links `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Website/AdminSection/CSS/main.css" />` should be fine